# How to run and debug Boomerang decompiler on Eclipse Neon

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, decompiler

I'm doing my thesis on Boomerang decompiler. I can compile it by terminal commands. But I want to use some IDE so that the coding can be easier. Now I'm using Eclipse. But I don't know how to build and run it with Eclipse. Usually, with terminal I will run these commands to build the project:

```
./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" "CC=gcc -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "CXX=g++ -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"
make remote
make
```

Then I will run this to decompile a file:

```
./boomerang -o [output] -as8 [input]
```

So how can I do that with Eclipse?
By the way, can I debug the project with Eclipse?

Thanks you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I would be in your place, I'd rather use QtCreator for my every day C++ work, and specifically for the following two reasons (for your situation):

1. It's way faster than eclipse on older computers at least.
2. It has support for importing  autotools based projects (http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-projects-autotools.html) with full debugging support.

(And no, I'm not affiliated to the project by any means, I just have some of experience using both)

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. I wil make a little research on QtCreator to make final desicion on which tool to use.

Comment: Hi @fritzone, I can run my project with QtCreator now, thank you so much. But when I run the debug mode, it notice me that: "This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.
Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail." Do you know how to fix this?